# HTML javascript checkbox function

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, android-camera

I have a scenario where, when I check Bills Available checkbox, a Image Upload camera function should pop-up. I can write the came function for "Image Upload" later. But i need "Image Upload" displayed when I check "Bills Available"

```
function calc()
{
var update=false;
console.log("update is" + update);
}

<td><input class="pop" id="exp" type="checkbox"  name="bill available" value="" onchange="calc();"/>Bill available<br></td>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. HINT: SHOW CODE. Other hint: `<input type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').style.display=this.checked?'block':'none'" />`

Comment: Well get to it :) start by having a go or show what you've tried.

Comment: <td><input class="pop" id="exp" type="checkbox"  name="bill available"  value="" onchange="calc();"/>Bill available<br></td>

Comment: function calc()
{
var update=true;
console.log("update is" + update);}

Comment: Add the code in the question, not in comments. The edit button is below the tags. And be sure to use the code block tool (`{}` icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("exp").onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById('upload').className = this.checked ? '' : 'hide';
   }
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("exp").onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById('upload').className = this.checked ? '' : 'hide';
   }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input class="pop" id="exp" type="checkbox" name="bill_available" value="" /><label for="exp">Bill available</label>
<div class="hide" id="upload">Upload</div>
```

Using your code after cleaning it up:

```js
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("exp").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('upload').className = this.checked ? '' : 'hide';
      }
    }
```

```css
    .hide {
      display: none
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="pop" id="exp" type="checkbox" name="bill_available" value="" />
      <label for="exp">Bill available</label>
    </td>
    <td class="hide" id="upload">
      <img id="p2" src="./images/camera 40.PNG" style="width:30px;height:30px;" 
      onclick="window.location='4s.html'" /><b>Image Upload</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked :) I just have to apply formatting styles with an image icon for it and append Camera functionality to it. Do you suggest I use a diff way to implement this?

Comment: This is how I modified The code:  {    <td><input class="pop" id="exp" type="checkbox" name="bill_available" value="" /><label for="exp">Bill available</label><td>
<td><b><div class="hide"id="upload"><img id="p2" src="./images/camera 40.PNG" style="width:30px;height:30px;" onclick="javascript:window.location='4s.html'" />Image Upload</b></td></div>    }

Comment: I would not use inline JavaScript and I would likely not use a table. Also the `javascript:` pseudo label is not needed in the event handler

Comment: For the same piece of code you helped me with, how can i include uncheck on-change option?

Comment: What do you mean? My code hides when unchecked and shows when checked

Comment: When I check the box "Bills Available" "Image Upload" option pops up. I would want that to disappear when I uncheck "Bills Available"

Comment: Yes that is what the ternary test does. Changes the class name depending on checked or not

Comment: Did you try the snippet?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the snippet. When I check I get the desired option. But when I un-check , the option does not disappear.

Comment: It does on my PC in Chrome and IE